# How long does it take for sqlserver.exe to remove the lock local database file?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have an application, which does a couple of selects, and then some inserts.  Probably does this about 200 times, then drops the connections and closes everything (as far as I can tell).  Here is the code:

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
  using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FrameBudgetDB"].ToString()))
  {
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT TOP 1 category_id FROM businesses WHERE '{0}' LIKE CONCAT('%',description,'%')", transDescription.Replace("'", "''"));
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    try
    {
      if (reader.HasRows)
      {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
          categoryId = (int)reader[0];
        }
      }
      else
      {
        categoryId = 11; // Extgra Expenses
      }
    }
    finally
    {
      reader.Close();                      
      cmd.Dispose();  
    }


    // Get Transaction Type
    int transTypeId = 0;
    cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT trans_type_id FROM transaction_types WHERE description = '{0}'", transType);
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    try
    {
      if (reader.HasRows)
      {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
          transTypeId = (int)reader[0];
        }
      }
    }
    finally
    {
      reader.Close();
      cmd.Dispose();
    }

    try
    {
      cmd = new SqlCommand();
      cmd.Connection = conn;
      cmd.CommandText = string.Format(
        "BEGIN " +
          "IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM transactions " +
                   "WHERE transaction_date = @TransDate " +
                   "AND trans_type_id = @TransTypeId " +
                   "AND amount = @Amount " +
                   "AND ((from_bank = 1 AND description = @TransDesc) " +
                    "OR (from_bank = 0)) " +
                   "AND(category_id = @CategoryId OR previous_category_id = @CategoryId )) " +
           "BEGIN " +
             "INSERT INTO transactions(transaction_date, description, trans_type_id, import_date, category_id, amount, from_bank) " +
             "VALUES(@TransDate, @TransDesc, @TransTypeId, @ImportDate, @CategoryId, @Amount, 1) " +
           "END " +
        "END");
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TransDate", transDate);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TransDesc", transDescription);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TransTypeId", transTypeId);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Amount", amount);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CategoryId", categoryId);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImportDate", DateTime.Now);
      rowsInserted = rowsInserted + cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      cmd.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
    conn.Close();
    conn.Dispose();                 
  }
  scope.Complete();
  scope.Dispose();
}
}
```

After all the inserts, I want do a backup of the db by copying and moving it elsewhere, however sqlserver.exe holds a lock on the file for ages.  I've tried having the application wait but it seems to be holding the lock for a really long time.

I have built a lock-checking while loop, but it would be nice to know how long it should actually take?

Comment: Why not make a backup with the actual SQL Server backup methods?

Comment: Can you do that using SQL Lite?

Answer (score 1):

Seems there is a problem in last part of code executing inserts.

Because SqlCommand is disposed in last line inside try..catch it may not execute at all if exception occurs.

Better would be to use separate SqlCommands inside usings to make sure everything is disposed properly.
It might be a reason why connection stays opened.
Your code:

```
try
{
  cmd = new SqlCommand();
  cmd.Connection = conn;
  ...
  rowsInserted = rowsInserted + cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  cmd.Dispose(); // <- This line might not be executed if exception occurs in previous line
}
```

Proposed correction:

```
try
{
  using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
  {
       cmd.Connection = conn;
       ...
       rowsInserted = rowsInserted + cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       // Call dispose is not needed
  }
}
```

Comment: I put an extra cmd.dispose inside the catch.

I tried this method, but it doesn't release the lock any quicker.  I timed it a number of times in both configurations, and it seems to take around 2m for the lock on the file to be released.

So at this point, I'm just getting the code to wait a couple of minutes before executing.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you want to copy files, not make a backup. Then in fact files might be "in use" for longer time. In such case I would suggest to stop sqlserver service before copying files using i.e. net stop <service name> and after copying start it again.

Comment: Bit hesitant to force stop the service in case it screws up the connected db at the time the service I halted.

Comment: In fact stoping service should cause commiting all things into files. But why you don't consider making backup - it is more clean way to move/backup database.

Comment: I might try stopping the service.  I will look into some better backup solutions in the future, but at the moment while I'm still developing and making db structural changes regularly, I've been copying the data back into DEV, making changes and rolling the changes back out with the data still in tact in the database.  

Basically, just being lazy, and not wanting to do it in SQL update scripts to alter the structure.  Probably something I should look into.